# Check each row of datagridview and get value of column(s)

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview that is populated with a couple of rows. I not sure where to start to loop the grid from row 1 to the last row and check some values on two of the columns. My grid looks like this, I need to check the values of r1:c1 and r1:c4 using a loop. my c1 is checkbox column by the way.

```
   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
r1 true    4    5   5   5            
r2 false   4    5   5   5
r3 false   8    6   4   5
r4 false   5    1   2   3
r5 false   4    1   2   1
```

I've tried:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In datagrid.Rows
        If row.Cells("column1").Value = True Then
            Dim getValue As String
            getValue = row.Cells("column4").Value
            msgbox(getValue)
        End If
Next
```

Problm is, if any cell in column 1 is true, getValue is still getting set the value in column4. I only want the column4 value if column 1 row is true.

Comment: Are you asking for a tutorial?  Have you tried anything? If so where are you stuck?  Please read: [Ask] and also take the [Tour]

Comment: @Plutonix check edited post.

Comment: If you want to do something for false, you need an `Else`.  None of *those* column1 values will ever be false.  you dont need a loop if you `need to check the values of r1:c1 and r1:c4`

Comment: Your grid is full of numbers but you're talking about values being true or false.  That makes no sense.  Please describe what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Let me rephrase my post, If first col1 row 1 is true, I want col 4 row 1  value, but the problem I'm getting to is, if col1 row 3 is true, my "getValue" is still getting the value from col4 row 1.

Comment: That still makes no sense. How can any field be true when they're all numbers?

Comment: I edit my post, col1 is checkbox column sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm using for the same purpose as you, but i'm checking for Strings/Integers so not sure how it would translate to boolean, and it works for returning a `value of column 4-row(i)` when you check the `value of column 1-row(i)`. Hope this helps at least.

```
    For i = 0 To YourDataGridHere.RowCount - 1
        If Not (YourDataGridHere.Rows(i).Cells("Column1").Value = 0) Then
            MsgBox(YourDataGridHere.Rows(i).Cells("Column4").Value)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Let me rephrase my post, If first col1 row 1 is true, I want col 4 row 1  value, but the problem I'm getting to is, if col1 row 3 is true, my "getValue" is still getting the value from col4 row 1.

Comment: Ahh, understand now, I did something similar to this not that long ago, Felt like a right hack but worked, I'll see if i can find it and adjust my answer to suit.